# vite: how to handle "require" statement in third-party module?

Tags: javascript, vite

I use an UI library which has "require" statement.

I can use vite to run development mode successfully.

but when I build and preview the dist, the browser fail: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`, because there are some "require" statement in the vendor chunk.

I have tried `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve`,  `@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs`  but it doesn't work.

How can I fix that ?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 5):

The `transformMixedEsModules: true` option worked for me.

Here is an example of `vite.config.ts` to handle **third-party modules** that use **require** statement for a React web app.

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    commonjsOptions: {
      transformMixedEsModules: true,
    },
  }
})
```

Answer (score -2):

You can fix it by using bundler like Webpack or Rollup to build your application for production. These bundlers can handle the `require` statements and convert them into valid JavaScript that can run in a browser. In your Rollup configuration, you can add the `@rollup/plugin-commonjs` plugin to handle the `require` statements. Then, instead of using Vite to build and preview the dist, use Rollup with the following command:

```
rollup -c
```

This will run the Rollup build process using the configuration specified in your `rollup.config.js` file.

`@rollup/plugin-node-resolve`, `@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs` sometimes don't work if the library you are using has dependencies that are not compatible with CommonJS.

Comment: But cannot be done using vite? because rollup not an option. I would not like to modify build

Answer (score -3):

many library provide 'run esmodule' method. or try replace require() to import